# DDLog doen't output logs to Console.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoalumberjack

I write following code in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
[[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] setColorsEnabled:YES];
[DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
```

But, it doesn't send log to Console.app.

How can I send it to console app?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Did you set the log level to a sufficiently verbose level?

Comment: Kevin,

Thanks. Yes, I set the log level to verbose level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're expecting issues that [were fixed](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/pull/234) few days ago. Those fixes will go to 1.8.2.

Meantime, you can grab latest version from [github](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), or use `pod 'CocoaLumberjack', :head` in case if you're using CocoaPods.

Comment: Dmitry,Thanks a lot for the information.

It resolved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Do you called below method?

```
[DDLog addLogger:DDFileLogger_Object];
```

See below code example

```
//For Apple's console
[DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
//For terminal:
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

NSString* logsDirectory = [LoggerManager logsDirectory];
DDLogFileManagerDefault* logFileManager = [[DDLogFileManagerDefault alloc] initWithLogsDirectory:logsDirectory];
fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] initWithLogFileManager:logFileManager];
// Configure File Logger
[fileLogger setMaximumFileSize:MAX_FILES_SIZE];
[fileLogger setRollingFrequency:ROLLING_FREQUENCY];
[[fileLogger logFileManager] setMaximumNumberOfLogFiles:MAX_NUMBER_OF_FILES];
[DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];
```

Answer (score 1):

For **deployment target iOS 10.0**, make sure you are using the new **DDOSLogger** like this:

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDOSLogger sharedInstance]]; // Uses os_log
```

and not DDTTYLogger or DDASLLogger.

Reference: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack#how-to-get-started

---

**Swift Usage**

Usually, you can simply `import CocoaLumberjackSwift`. If you installed CocoaLumberjack using CocoaPods, you need to use `import CocoaLumberjack` instead.

```
DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance) // Uses os_log

let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() // File Logger
fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
DDLog.add(fileLogger)

...

DDLogVerbose("Verbose")
DDLogDebug("Debug")
DDLogInfo("Info")
DDLogWarn("Warn")
DDLogError("Error")
```

**Obj-C usage**
If you're using Lumberjack as a framework, you can `@import CocoaLumberjack;`. Otherwise, `#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>`

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDOSLogger sharedInstance]]; // Uses os_log

DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init]; // File Logger
fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hour rolling
fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7;
[DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];

...

DDLogVerbose(@"Verbose");
DDLogDebug(@"Debug");
DDLogInfo(@"Info");
DDLogWarn(@"Warn");
DDLogError(@"Error");
```